# Convert INSERT sequence into UPDATE sequence

Tags: sql, pdo, syntax, insert, sequence

i have a SQL INSERT sequence in PDO like:

```
INSERT INTO property (id,name,addres...) VALUES (:id,:name,:address...)
```

And i want to do a UPDATE sequence, with the same fields. The problem is that i have 150 fields and about 3 or 4 different sequences, so if i make the update syntax manually its probably that it takes a lot of time and a lot of mistakes, is there any "automatic" way to convert it?

Thank you a lot

Comment: You can use Excel (or another spreadsheet) as a code generator.

Comment: You have 150 columns?  Are you sure you can't improve your table structure to avoid this?

Comment: Its a real estate db, it contains a lot of different info about the properties...

Comment: Ah I see, sounds messy! :( - Honestly its a painful process but I'm afraid you'd probably have to write this manually ( I guess you are writing some procedures? )

Comment: May I ask, why do you need to update every field on each query? Surely you should only need to update certain fields as they change, therefore your query would only be as long as it needs to be

Comment: Its because i have an "add property" form with those 150 fields and with that huge insert, and now i'm making the "edit property" form, that is the same add property form, but with the inputs values loaded from the db, so i think the most easy way to do this is execute an update with the same 150 fields...

Comment: I'm thinking to do a PHP script with 2 arrays that makes my sequence... but its strange that this doesn't exists yet no?

Comment: @EstebanCazorla I think you read my mind ;)

Comment: So what if it's a lot of typing?  You only have to do it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this, is have a function which dynamically builds the query based on key-value pairs passed in an array:

```
function updateTable($table, $values) 
{
    // Set the base query
    $query = 'UPDATE ' . $table;

    // Build the query with the key value pairs
    foreach($values as $key=>$data) {
        $query . ' SET ' . $key . ' = ' . $data . ' ';
    }

    // Execute your query here
    ...
}
```

Obviously you would need to bind your PDO objects on each iteration of the loop but I wanted to give you the basic layout of a loop to handle what you want to achieve, you could then call it like this:

```
updateTable('Products', { 'product_name' => 'Apple', 'product_price' => 100.00})
```

This would then build the query:

```
UPDATE Products SET product_name = 'Apple', product_price = 100.00
```

You could easily extend this query to provide a `WHERE` parameter so you can refine your UPDATE query - please remember this is currently in-secure so please spend some time implementing proper sanitsation over variables before committing to the DB!

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem - if you have problems extending for `WHERE` functionality let me know - not at home on my computer, hard to answer questions on my phone :P - good luck!

Comment: Just remember without a WHERE clause, all records in the table will be updated ;)